# onchange joomla JHTML

Tags: javascript, forms, function, joomla, onchange

How can i put an onchange function in this JHTML?

```
<?php
echo JHTML::_('calendar', $this->row->dates, 'dates', 'dates', '%Y-%m-%d',
               array('class' => 'inputbox required validate-date') );
?>
```

I imagine it would be something like this but it breaks the calendar code:

```
<?php 
echo JHTML::_('calendar', $this->row->dates, 'dates', 'dates', '%Y-%m-%d',
              'onchange=\"thisfunction(this.form)\"', array('class' => 'inputbox required validate-date') ); 
?>
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest binding events via script, rather than having them in your markup.  You'll find it easier to maintain and won't have to deal with where the markup is coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JHTML::_('calendar'...` is actually calling [JHTML::calendar](http://api.joomla.org/__filesource/fsource_Joomla-Platform_HTML_librariesjoomlahtmlhtml.php.html#a851) passing your parameters. So if you take a look at the API you'll find:

```
@param   array   $attribs  Additional HTML attributes
```

This implies that your 6th param could be a array with additional HTML attributes. So you could just pass *onchange* in that array like:

```
echo JHTML::_('calendar', null, 'dates', 'dates', '%Y-%m-%d',
              array(
                    'class' => 'inputbox required validate-date',
                    'onchange' => 'thisfunction(this.form)'
              ));
```